# window.location.replace is not working

Tags: javascript

```
function setInit(){
    iu.init({
        saveFile : 'store/saveImageFile'
        ,CallBackOnSave : function (s){
            console.log("redirect");
            window.location.replace("store/details");
        }
    });
}
```

`iu` is an image upload module which has no issues. In fact I can see the console log of **redirect**.

problem is, the same page gets reloaded, instead of going to the url in replace.

tried other ways like **href** as well, sadly the same result.

Comment: Have you tried using assign?

Comment: How does your image uploader work? Could it be accessing the wrong window?

Comment: just a guess, may be you need to prevent default or something.

Comment: Any chance a server redirection takes place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
window.location.href = "store/details";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
parent.window.location.href = "store/details";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use by this way,

#### Syntax

```
window.location.href = window.location.host + relativePath 
window.location.href = relativePath
```

#### example

```
window.location.href = "store/details";
window.location.href = window.location.host + 'store/details';
```